# Libgdx drag and drop crashes when starting drag

Tags: java, libgdx

Whenever i begin to drag an item in the inventory it immediately crashes throwing a null pointer exception. The only way that I have found working is if I set the drag actor to the actual slot instead of the item, but I don't want to be dragging the slot with the item.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragAndDrop$1.drag(DragAndDrop.java:110)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragListener.touchDragged(DragListener.java:61)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:62)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchDragged(Stage.java:315)
at com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer.touchDragged(InputMultiplexer.java:135)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:363)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:221)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:128)
```

Comment: What version of LibGDX are you using? What is line 110 of DragAndDrop? Can you show some code that makes use of the InputProcessor.

Comment: @Jason, i'm using the latest version of libgdx, and 110 of DragAndDrop is libgdx's class, not mine.

Here's the code for line 110:
if (target != null) actor = isValidTarget ? payload.validDragActor : payload.invalidDragActor;

Comment: Looks like there might be an issue here; https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5675 Feel free to comment or create an issue on LibGDX's GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is definitely with the newer versions of libgdx. I switched to an older version and it's working fine now.